# Import CSV File for HTML preview

Tags: c#, html, csv

I'm simply trying to represent a CSV file in html. It almost works except the last value in the array is not showing, and the second to last value takes the space of the last value. For example,

```
XXXXX | a | b | c | d | e | f |    g       |   h
19215   11  10  3   1   5   1   $2,320.00   $1,215.00 
91158   2   2   0   2   0   0   $350.00     $0.00 
19261   2   1   1   0   0   1   $50.00      $0.00
```

^ csv file

When I show the data in html I get this.... 
< 19215 || 11 || 10 || 3 || 1 || 5 || 1 || 2 || 320.00 > // for the first row notice how 2320 is split into two arrays and the h column doesn't even show.... not sure what's going on. here is the relevant source code....

```
<h3>@foreach (var element in Model)
                {
                    <p>
                   <@element.XXXXX ||
                    @element.a ||
                    @element.b ||
                    @element.c ||
                    @element.d ||
                    @element.e ||
                    @element.f ||
                    @element.g ||
                    @element.h>
                </p>
                }
                </h3>

public static CsvExtract readCsv(String s)
        {
            string[] values = s.Split(',');
            CsvExtract extract = new CsvExtract();
            extract.XXXXX = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
            extract.a = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
            extract.b = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);
            extract.c= Convert.ToInt32(values[3]);
            extract.d = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]);
            extract.e = Convert.ToInt32(values[5]);
            extract.f = Convert.ToInt32(values[6]);
            extract.g = (Convert.ToString((values[7].Replace("$", "")).Replace("\"", "")));
            extract.h = (Convert.ToString(values[8].Replace("$","").Replace("\"","")));

            return extract;
        }
        public List<CsvExtract> stuff()
        {
            alist = File.ReadAllLines("retrycsv.csv")
                        .Skip(1)
                        .Select(v => CsvExtract.readCsv(v))
                        .ToList();
            return alist;
        }
```

Comment: Hint: `string[] values = s.Split(',');` - btw. your *csv* does not look like a valid one. you may post a more correct one so others can help you a bit better.

Comment: What's going on is that you're splitting on `,` and the value `$2,320.00` contains that `char` so it gets split...

Comment: Wow, thank you. I completely overlooked the comma in the actual dollars lol